# All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, redhat, centos8, epel

I'm unable to install nginx in centos 8.

I already installed epel-release

Here is the output

```
[root@ip-172-31-31-168 centos]# yum install nginx
Last metadata expiration check: 0:29:57 ago on Wed 16 Feb 2022 12:57:09 PM UTC.
All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: nginx
Error: Unable to find a match: nginx

[root@ip-172-31-31-168 centos]# yum install -y epel-release
Last metadata expiration check: 0:30:39 ago on Wed 16 Feb 2022 12:57:09 PM UTC.
Package epel-release-8-14.el8.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Comment: You see the `All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: nginx`. So you must have set `excludepkgs` in  your `yum` configuration. Otherwise, post contents of your `.repo` files.